# How to make selected item to change class(How to make property observable in backbone)

Tags: backbone.js

i want to build simple screen, where list of items in one side and selected item details -on another. when user click on one of the items - its details displayed in 'details' section.
also the selected item  in the 'list' section must be decorated with 'active' class.
here is my router code:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes:{
    "":"list",
    "users/:id":"userDetails"
},
list:function () {

    this.usersList = new UsersCollection(usersList);/* new UsersCollection()*/
    var self = this;


    //this.userList.fetch({
       // success: function () {
           this.UsersListView =   new UsersListView({ model: this.usersList });
           $('#sidebar').html(this.UsersListView.render().el);
       // }
    //})//end of fetch


},
userDetails:function (id) {

    if(this.usersList){
        //unselect prevously selected
        if(this.user )this.user.set({'selected':false});

        this.user = this.usersList.get(id);

        //select current
        this.user.set({'selected':true});
        //empty refill the items section
        this.UsersListView =   new UsersListView({ model: this.usersList });
        $('#sidebar').empty().html(this.UsersListView.render().el);


        if (this.UserDetailsView) this.UserDetailsView.close();
        this.UserDetailsView = new UserDetailsView({model:this.user});

        $('#content').html(this.UserDetailsView.render().el);
    }
    else{

    }
}
});
```

So far i managed to set the 'active' item class by emptying and refill the items section html. 
Is there any way to observe (like in knockoutjs) the 'selected' property, so once it changes -the change will be visible in html?

code of view:

```
window.UserListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:"li",

    template:_.template($('#tpl-user-list-item').html()),

    render:function (eventName) {
        if(this.model.get('selected')){$(this.el).addClass('active');}
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

        return this;
    }
});
```

Thanks forwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) is what you're looking for (especially the Events#listenTo method).
So; in your view:

```
initialize: function() {
  // listen to your model
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:selected', this.updateClass);
},
updateClass: function() {
  // something like...
  this.$el.toggleClass('active');
}
```